# How manage log4net to log into specific Url or Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I have Web App and I want send my logs (with **Log4Net**) `(Error-Info-Warning)` with query string into Specific url OR Send logs to the web service that I created it before?

Comment: Can you specify your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement a custom appender by implementing the `AppenderSkeleton`. In the appender you can call the webservice you have created to save your logging records.

```
public class FooAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
     protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
     {
        // Do something with the logged data, like calling your web url
     }
}
```

and than configure it like:

```
<appender name="Foo"type="FooBar.FooAppender, FooBarAppender">
   <threshold value="ERROR" />
   <CallingApp value="BarApp" />
</appender>
```

Comment: Thank You ! it works and i fund some other example that use right you tell ! http://twitterappender.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#514714